# Android: EditText.getText().toString returns nothing

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

I want to get value from an edittext view in an `onClick` method, but there seems to be some problems retrieving the id of the `EditText`.
here is my code:

```
public class CreateEvent extends Activity{
    Button cbutton;
    EditText title;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstacesState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_event_layout);

        cbutton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.cbutton);
        title = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.title);

        cbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.v("title", title.getText().toString());
        });
    }
}
```

Also I tried to move initiation of title into `onClick`, still nothing returned.
Not sure what to do.

this is the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
android:oriention = "vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
    />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:hint="@string/title"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with my layout file.

Comment: What you have should work. Did you write anything in your EditText?

Comment: What about getEditableText() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getEditableText() ?

Comment: Do you get any errors and does "returns nothing" mean that it returns and empty string or `null`?

Comment: did u check your logcat?

Comment: @Sam definitely... I just cannot get anything from it...

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i did, no warning or error caught...

Comment: What about `View.OnClickListener()` instead of `Button.OnClickListener()`?

Comment: @codeMagic no error. yes, nothing. And it seems that title is not pointing to the view I meant.

Comment: Is your EditText in R.layout.create_event_layout? If not findVieById returns null

Comment: I think there is something else wrong with my code. And this piece of coding is exactly right. thanks guys! @nfirex

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. You should post it as a solution if you think it will help future visitors, or try to delete your question if you think it's just a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

//there is notting wrong in your layout

Just you forgot to declare the Button there `(R.id.cbutton)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button cbutton;
EditText title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cbutton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    title = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    cbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick (View v){
            Log.v("title", title.getText().toString()); 
        }
        }//missing i think 
            );


}
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by describing what you have changed and why it should work.

Comment: i think there is a missing bracket in code.i just tested it myself right now

Answer (score 0):

there is no button in your layout file with this id

```
cbutton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.cbutton);
```

In your layout file i didnt see the id cbutton . also put this check

```
 String value = title.getText().toString();
if(edittext.length==0){ Log.d("null","the valueis null")};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the view has the right id

```
if (v.getId() == title.getId())
{
   Log.v("title", title.getText().toString()); 
}
```

and the button isn't defined in the XML file, or is it in another XML file?